# Supermicro X8DAH+-F wont see more than 64GB

Tags: memory, supermicro

I have 12 ECC DIMM (similar Kingston KVR1066, 8GB everyone) and installed it according to the scheme from instruction - 1AB2AB3AB on both memory blocks (P1 and P2), but system see only 64GB instead of 96. 
All memory blocks are working without errors separately. So, schemes 1ABC2ABC not working, scheme 1ABC2ABC3AB showing only 16GB on single CPU, scheme 1AB2AB shows correct 32GB, but 1AB3AB shows 16 GB only.

I don't know, why I get this, but system see only 64GB max(32GB per processor).
Maybe someone know, what I must do?
BIOS updating, CMOS and NVRAM resetting didn't help.

[Supermicro X8DAH+-F](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DAH_-F.cfm)

**Update**: Two Xeon E5645 CPUs, 12 Kingston KVR1066D3Q8R7S/8G
**Update2**: Memtest86+ showed that DIMM1 slots on both blocks are always empty. Why?

Comment: What CPUs do you have? Do they support more than 32GB?

Comment: Two Xeon 5645 installed

Comment: Well, you're indeed correct... With the motherboard/CPU/RAM combination, this should indeed work.  Had your memory *not* been registered - yes, even if it was EEC - you would be limited to 48GB of RAM as per your motherboard's specification.  However, I've verified that [those RAM modules are indeed registered](http://www.valueram.com/datasheets/kvr1066D3Q8R7S_4G.pdf) and have EEC.  What happens if you **lower** the RAM frequency or increase the RAM latency/timings?

Comment: This RAM are ECC-registered and motherboard supports up to 288GB of Registered RAM (RDIMM). 
So, the default action of this motherboard with a big RAM is reducing memory frequency to 800MHz, what MB does automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found source. 
This problem caused by damaged pins on both sockets. On Socket1(P1) I'm repaired pins just by setting correct direction using needle. On Socket2(P2) one pin was turned apart, so DIMM3 not working. 
In the future I'll replace or repair this motherboard. I hope so this damaged pin will not cause any other problems, because currently I can work without additional 16GB of RAM.